# Why are posts protected by Community?

Tags: support, community, question-protection

I just saw this post:

[How do I prevent Tiny Death Star from crashing when trying to collect an imperial items reward?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147583/how-do-i-prevent-tiny-death-star-from-crashing-when-trying-to-collect-an-imperia#comment209248_147583)

It doesn't seem like a really important post, why the need to protect it?

Comment: Importance is not why posts are protected, it is the amount of spam/low quality content they attract. Tiny Death Star questions are racking up huge views at the moment, and as a result are getting lots of bad answers. As @badp has pointed out, once three posts have been deleted, Community will automatically protect the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Community protects questions that get three deleted posts from new users (9 or less rep). In this case, the question got three "me too!" posts. Two of these were deleted by moderators, the third (apparently) [through the review queue.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/65532)

Comment: Does this include self deleted questions made by high rep users?

Comment: @Esq I doubt it, unless maybe the post had flags attached to it anyway.

Comment: @Esq I don't think deleting a question can cause it to be protected.

Comment: It only affects things with deleted posts from new users - answers from users with at least 10 reputation do not count towards auto-protection.

Answer (score 3):

As I don't haver 10k rep I can't see deleted posts I can't tell for certain, but probably because it got a couple spam/thank you posts.

If my memory server me right I've read somewhere that after three deleted posts, community will automatically protect the question.

15k rep users can also protect a question that gathers spam answers.